# Using python to separate files on local drive

Tags: python, file, debugging, move, shutil

I have several image/files on my computer. All of which start like this 1214455.jpeg
Each image is either a cat or a dog. The digits is a serial number that can be found in the database.
I want to separate images for cat and dog, and place them into two separate folders.
Every image has a name, which is the same serial number.
I want to be able to use a tuple of serial number / names as string to find the names of cats and dog. Then separate them.

```py
source_dir = "C:\\     \\file1"

destination_dir = (
    "C:\\       cats"
)

destination_dir = (
    "C:\\       dogs"
)


file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)

files = os.listdir(source_dir)

output=("123344", "345566", "8888887")

for file_name_i in files:
    # for file_name_i in os.listdir(current_dir):  # to search in sub folders
    # if the file starts with a number as string in the list, place in cancer folder if not place in health
    if os.path.join(source_dir, file_name_i).startswith(output):

        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name_i), destination_dir, "cats")

    else:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name_i), destination_dir, "dogs")
```

This code only remove every image. It is unable separate the animals.

Comment: You have a single source directory. You can't have multiple files with the same name in one directory. Cancer? Health? Cats? Dogs? All very confusing

Comment: you have assigned `destination_dir` twice, so the second assignment will overwrite the first. Your instructions will move files to either `C:\dogs\cats`  or `C:\dogs\dogs` depending on the result of the conditional.  You are also missing a double backslash in the destination folder. Should be `C:\\dogs`

Answer (score 0):

shutil.move takes 3 arguments `(source, destination, copy_function)`, and you are passing `(source, destination, copy_function="cats")` or `copy_function="dogs"` respectively.

Leave the third argument blank (unless there is a copy function you want to use), and instead of `destination_dir` use `f"{destination_dir}/cats"` , and `f"{destination_dir}/dogs"` respectively.